# Hp tablet TX2001au Media Center Features on Vista home Premium

Tags: windows-vista, tablet, media-center

I got a [Hp tablet TX2001au](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=3653674&lc=en&dlc=&cc=us&lang=&softwareitem=ob-77258-1&dest_page=product&os=4062)   with Windows Vista Home premium 32 bit. It has media center features too. But I rarely use it and they hog all the recourses. But Vista loads all the services to support the Media Center features like the QuickPlay service etc . I want to write a batch script with which i can start and stop those services : something like `tabletmediacenter.bat -start` . Which are the Media Center services ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up a command prompt and enter in

```
net start
```

That will show you a list of all started services and they're respective names. From there you can probably look at them by specific names and determine which ones to add to your script. I'd say you should experiment with them and Google the name of each service to determine what it truly is.

Comment: I'd also like to add that you can write out the content to file for easy copy-n-paste: `net start > started.txt`

Comment: its kind of a rhetorical question........ but Which are the windows Media Center services ??